# Change language Samsung S8+

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, locale

I am facing a change language issue in Samsung S8+ (android 9.0). 
I have uploaded one release **.aab**("Android App Bundle format") file extension to the google play store of My Application. 
Now I am getting this application on play store and I can easily download. 
I have installed this application on multiple devices and works perfectly.

But when I changed the language on Samsung S8+ device is not working. 
In our application, we are using two language English and Japanese but why not works in Samsung S8+ device I don't know and another device its works nice.

Then I have installed release **.apk** on Samsung S8+ and its working. So I want to know why **.aab** is not works and **.apk** works. please give your answer.

Please check used code

this is base method for change language

```
public void updateLocale() {
    String locality = MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedPref().getLanguage();
    if (locality != null && !locality.isEmpty() && locality.equals(Locale.ENGLISH.toString())) {
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            configuration.setLocale(new Locale(Locale.ENGLISH.toString()));
        } else {
            configuration.locale = new Locale(Locale.ENGLISH.toString());
        }
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        onConfigurationChanged(configuration);
    } else {
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            configuration.setLocale(new Locale(Locale.JAPANESE.toString()));
        } else {
            configuration.locale = new Locale(Locale.JAPANESE.toString());
        }
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        onConfigurationChanged(configuration);
    }
}
```

On Change language screen

```
Switch svChangeLang;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSharedPref = new SharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
    svChangeLang = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.sv_change_lang);

    String lanCode = mSharedPref.getLanguage();
    if (lanCode.equals(Locale.ENGLISH.toString()))
        svChangeLang.setChecked(true);
    else
        svChangeLang.setChecked(false);

    svChangeLang.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isChecked)
                svChangeLang.setChecked(false);
            else
                svChangeLang.setChecked(true);
            mSharedPref.setLanguage(isChecked ? Locale.ENGLISH.toString() : 
            Locale.JAPANESE.toString());

            updateLocale();
        }
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with app bundles by default: Google Play only downloads resources when the device's selected languages change.

[Solution First](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#lang_resources)

**Solution Second:**

```
android {
bundle {
    language {

        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```

}

But the second solution increase app sie